# error: The named parameter 'child' isn't defined in Dart Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

For some reason it's throwing me this error for line 19 (highlighted)

```
The named parameter 'child' isn't defined.
```

Is there anything I'm not seeing?

Thanks!

-T

[image]

Comment: `AppBar` doesn't have `child` parameter. You need to remove that part.

Comment: instead of child use `action:[RaisedButton())` in `appbar`. no child properties in appbar

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך You nailed it.  Thanks!